# Facebook message: This page isn't available. The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed

Tags: facebook

When going to the following Facebook page:

https://www.facebook.com/pg/rociojurado

I get the following message:

```
This page isn't available

The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed
```

I REALLY want to claim that name for my facebook page, but i don't know what the message means, or if i can even claim it, or how to contact whomever is responsible for that page...

Can i contact Facebook and explain to them that i want that page username? What are my options, if any?
Does this mean that the username will NEVER be available EVER?